# How to create a simple form and pass one of its fields to a script in another page

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I need to work with a plugin called [AffiniBox](https://affinibox.com.br/), which I'm going to integrate it in a mobile app (displayed as a webpage). To authenticate a users login, I'll have to create a form with a couple of fields, one of them being e-mail. Essentially, I'll have to pass the content of the e-mail field as an ID to a script in another page.

The script in the other page will then fetch the e-mail and load itself.

I'm thinking that simple form fields such as "form action" and "input type" could be used, but I wouldn't know how to send this data to another page.

This is the code they've sent to me to work with. "data-email={{EMAIL}}" is the field id which should be filled with the form in the previous page.

```html
<div id="afbx-root" data-club="dridi" data-email="{{EMAIL}}"></div>
<script src="https://plugin.affinibox.com.br"></script>
<style>

.jss224 {
    height: auto !important;
}

.jss229 {
    padding-top: 50px !important;
    padding-bottom: 50px !important;
}

</style>
```

According to them, if no e-mail is inserted or if it's an invalid entry, the page should reload to the previous one.

Comment: The hyperlink 'AffiniBox' in your first sentence does not work.

Answer (score 0):

did u mean to redirect to another page with email ?

```
document.location.href = 'http://example.com?email=email@email.uk';
```

or u want to send a form ?

1st use form to send data to another page : 
here is important for u to name a input as it will be a name u will use on another page

```
<form action="http://example.com/" method="POST">
<input type="email" name="data-email" value="email@email.en">
</form>
```

on another_page.php :

u receive a POSTed data with :

```
$email = $_POST['data-email'];
```

and u can use it with javascript like this :

```
let email = <?php echo $email; ?> ;
```

so u have let email with value u sent with POST

Comment: I want to send a form. The first page should have a simple form with an e-mail field. The user will type his e-mail and, upon submission, will be redirected to the second page, which will run the script. The `data-email={{EMAIL}}` id should be defined by the e-mail form typed in the previous page.

Comment: ok , so if u will use form like above , after sending form u will send a data-email=youremail , and you will be redirecting with these data to page you set as ACTION in form  /// if you need an email in URL use GET method instead of POST

Comment: In this case, how should I edit my script code? `data-email={{EMAIL}}` is an id, how should I format this id code to receive the form from the previous page? Should it be the same name as set in the form? I've tried that but it doesn't work.

Comment: yes u should use data-email name like in previouse page //  but u cannot do that with javascript (as it is client-side language) , u need to use PHP or other server-side language to receive POSTed data , with PHP u receive this like this $email = $_POST['data-email'];   and u can use $email variable /// if u use PHP u can receive these data and put them to js variable like this : var my_javascript_variable = <?php echo $_POST['data-email'] ?>;

Comment: The script itself is written in javascript. How would I pass the POSTed data received with PHP to the javascript `data-email` id?

Comment: i edited answer to explain steps u want to make to POST and receive email